# Getting Image From Url And Sharing it not working in Android 10(Q)

Tags: java, android, permissions, share, android-fileprovider

i want to get an image from an url and share it i'm working on a wallpaper app where you browse images and when you want to share an image you click on the share button and there where this code is executed and i use this 
Code And it's Working on the all the Android Versions below Android Q
and i added the necessary permissions in the manifest and in the code and as i said it works just fine in all the other android versions except Q

i'm using Ion library here

```
    public class ShareTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        private Context context;
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        String path;
        File file;

        public ShareTask(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            pDialog.setMessage("Download ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            path = args[0];
            String idStr = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/Download/");
            dir.mkdirs();
            String fileName = idStr;
            file = new File(dir, fileName);
            Ion.with(getApplicationContext()).load(path)
                    .write(file);
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/*");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(SlideImageActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file));
            // SHARE URL
            share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share the photo"));
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

and i use this to execute it  i'm passing the url of the image

```
        (new ShareTask(SlideImageActivity.this)).execute(Constant.SERVER_IMAGE_UPFOLDER_CATEGORY + mAllImageCatName[position] +
            "/" + mAllImages[position]);
```

and in Android Q it gives me this in the Logcat

```
  java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri content://com.example.wallpaper.provider/external_files/Download/34496_8b4903cd52ec2e54cb85c3512978dee3-1.jpg from pid=22692, uid=1000 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
    at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:729)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:602)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceFilePermission(ContentProvider.java:593)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:507)
    at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:307)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
```

Comment: thank you form your comment, i think i wasn't clear enough i added it in the title but i will clear it up more
i want to get an image from an url and share it
i'm working on a wallpaper app where you browse images and when you want to share an image you click on the share button and there where this code is executed

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. That path is not usable under Android Q. Google for scoped storage.